# curlftpfs fails on speedport ftp

Tags: curlftpfs

I use `curlftpfs` for a lot of servers, but it fails for out speedport router. If I log in with filezilla,  I get forwarded to `/mnt/LexarUSB_Flash_Drive/16_STICK`.

When I have it mounted in a folder, I see no contents (although there is with filezilla), and when I try to create a new file, I get a permission denied.

Is there a way how I still could mount this?

---

With `curlftpfs "speedport.ip/mnt/LexarUSB_Flash_Drive/16_STICK" "$tempdir"` I get `Error connecting to ftp: Server denied you to change to the given directory`.

Comment: I do not entire understand your question, so using curlftp shows no files, but filezilla does?

Comment: Yes. Filezilla tells me that I get redirected to another folder, but curlftpfs just shows an empty folder.

Comment: I wonder if curlftp ignores the redirect that the ftp server tries to impose on the client.. some servers instead of chrooting the folder.. it issues a redirect command after successfull login... Can you issue a change folder command to the same folder as you see in filezilla on the curlftp? It should go there with no problem.

Comment: You mean to mount the root with curlftpfs and then drill into the tree? I do not see a single dir, so I guess this does not work. Or do you mean the whole path when connecting?

Comment: the whole path, the tree wont be available.

Comment: The whole path does not seem to work really, I updated the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1993/discussion-between-ppumkin-and-queueoverflow)